# ListView no data when opening app in landscape only

Tags: android, listview

I have a weird thing happening that I am not sure how to diagnose.  Here is the problem.

What works:
Opening app in portrait mode then turning to landscape mode - both orientations populate correctly.

What DOESN'T work:
Opening app in landscape mode - the listviews are empty.  But if I turn it to portrait it populates, then turn back to landscape, everything is still populated correctly.

This ONLY happens on app being loaded the first time and only if the phone is in landscape.  This behavior does not happen if the app is opened, screen turned off, phone turned to landscape, screen turned on.

Additional info:
The app is using a ViewPager and it opens to the first section fragment and the data for the listviews are populated before the fragments are initiated.  This happens correctly for both orientations.

Any ideas where I can start looking to diagnose what is going on?

--Edit
I am not sure what code would be useful, but here is some.  I have traced in debug the flow of the program and everything gets populated correctly but no ListViews.  The lists being passed thru are populated, the array adapter is generating the views correctly, everything looks correct but nothing appears on the screen.  Again, this is ONLY on the app's initial loading and ONLY when the phone starts out as landscape.  A quick flip to portrait and back and everything is fine.

the MainActivity's onCreate minus the page change listener

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rootactivitylayout);

        //create default and upgrade database
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        db.closeDB();

        ((ExtendedApp) this.getApplication()).initializeGlobals();
        PopulateUpgradeList(this);
        PopulateShipList(this);
        PopulateSquadronList(this);
        PopulateObjectiveList(this);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

The page fragment's onCreateView up to the first listview being populated

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        isLoading = true;
        thiscontext = container.getContext();

        //handle ships
        //------------------------
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragarmada, container, false);
        ArrayList<Ship> tmpList = justShipTypes();

        ShipAdapt = new AA_Armada_Ships(thiscontext, tmpList);
        ListView tmplv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvAShipList);

        tmplv.setAdapter(ShipAdapt);
        tmplv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            shipPopup((Ship) view.getTag());
            }
        });
```

Array Adapter's code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        isLoading = true;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowarmada_ships, parent, false);
        }

        Ship tmpShip = (Ship) getItem(position);

        ImageView tmpiv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivARowShipIcon_Header);
        TextView tmptv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvARowShipTitle_Header);
        LinearLayout tmpll = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llARowShipURL);
        CheckBox tmpOwned = (CheckBox) tmpll.findViewById(R.id.ckARowShipOwned);
        Button tmpURL = (Button) tmpll.findViewById(R.id.btnARowShipURL);

        Ship.setShipPic(tmpiv, tmpShip.Type ,true,false);
        tmptv.setText(tmpShip.Type);
        tmpOwned.setChecked(tmpShip.isOwned);
        tmpOwned.setTag(tmpShip);
        tmpURL.setTag(tmpShip.URL);

        tmpOwned.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton pckView, boolean pisChecked) {
                if(! isLoading) {
                    ((Ship) pckView.getTag()).setOwned((Activity) pckView.getContext());
                }
            }
        });

        tmpURL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse((String) view.getTag()));
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(tmpShip);
        isLoading = false;
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: CODE we need TEH CODE

Comment: ideas : add Logs to all the places you *think* the code is being ran, then read the logs

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you, what parameters did you have to modify? Originally from [Wallison Francisco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658080/wallison-francisco)

Comment: I had multiple nested layouts and one of the upper layers was set to Match Content on the width (pretty sure, it's been a couple weeks...).  Once I set that layout to Match Parent everything was good again.  I would suggest playing with the layout width/height and set static values to see which one is causing the error.  It doesn't matter if it looks good, you are just setting a static dp to figure out which one is in error so it can be fixed.  Hope that helps

Comment: A little supplemental idea - I think what is happening is the order of operations is just a little off for how I have my layouts nested and the listview is getting populated AFTER the layout is set and it is not triggering a redraw of the screen.  The flip back and forth corrects the population issue.  It is strange since it doesn't happen in portrait, but, whatevs

Answer (score 0):

Finally, finally figured out what was going on.  It had to do with the main layout's width setting and the second layer width setting.  For some reason, when in landscape and only on initial app start, the layout widths would not layer correctly and I would get a blank screen.

hoorrah!